# Cutler hammer breaker box installed in 79’

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

[image]

Would I be able to properly ground wire with this setup? Is the silver braided cable ground and how would I check it runs to a spike / water line ?

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please?

Comment: That's a neat and tidy install, specially considering its 45 years old.

Answer (score 7):

### This appears to be a Split-Bus / Rule of Six panel.

There is no main breaker. (unless a meter-main has been retrofit).

The top area of the panel is the home of *up to six* large 240V breakers. Together, all 6 of these are your "main breaker" to use the term loosely.   The breaker on the bottom left is called the "Lighting Main" * and feeds the breaker spaces below.

"What keeps a foolish person from stuffing the Rule of Six / main breaker area with too many loads (tankless water heat, EV charging) and overloading the service?" *Absolutely nothing, except every house is required to do a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation anytime something large is added. There's been no history of trouble with panels where the Load Calc is valid. But of course, people add things without doing that, eh?*

**CH is a modern top-shelf panel and the best panel on store shelves today**.  It is widely used in industrial applications and would not be out-of-place in the Tesla Gigafactory.

The only defect with this panel is that it is Rule of Six / split-bus. That would be corrected if it were fed from a "meter-main" outside.

### Service wires and grounding

Your service wires contain 2 hots and 1 neutral.  They are aluminum which is fine.  I'm guessing the braided aluminum plainly visible here comes in with the two service hots, and is the service neutral.

There is nothing wrong with aluminum for large wires like this. They need to be torqued to specification, but they usually are.  I see no problem here.

There should be a Grounding Electrode System consisting of a large and usually bare copper ground wire, running continuously to either ground rods, an UFER ground cast into the concrete and tied into the re-rod, or an old school connection to a metal water pipe.  Water pipe grounds are on the out because most water agencies are replacing with plastic meters and pipes.

Since this is the main panel, neutral and ground are bonded here only.  Thus ground appears to go to the neutral bar.

I see what looks like a #8 or #6 bare ground that seems to go off alone, and not as part of a cable with conductors. That is most likely it.   Try to follow the wire and/or search the perimeter of the house for ground rods. Also search the water service entrance for a cable clamp there.  To check continuity, run a wire and check for hard continuity between ground rod/clamp and neutral bar on the panel.

If you want to separate neutrals and grounds to make it easier to make this a sub panel in the future, Eaton sells accessory ground bars for this panel. Read your panel labeling and it will call out specific part numbers made to fit pre-tapped sites in your panel. They should be still made. Cutler Hammer has been a division of Eaton since 1968.    Eaton just started slapping their name over top of Cutler-Hammer for some reason.  So all the bits will say Eaton now.

### The panel seems to be sunk into the wall.  No go.

I am not sure, maybe it's parallax, but your panel seems to be submarined somewhat into the surface of the wall.  Or possibly someone added another layer of sheetrock after this panel was installed.  The panel cover is a flush mount cover that overlaps the sheetrock.

[It is never allowed for the cover to sit proud](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/215718/47125) over the edge of the panel.  That will cause the breakers to fall out if you throw them forcefully!

That will have to be milled or cut back. Feel free to frame it with a tasteful edge to hide the weirdness.

[image]

---

---

* Back in the 40s when this stuff was named, lighting was the "killer app" for electricity, with large 240V electric appliances only starting to make an entrance in earnest.

Answer (score 2):

The silver wire is your neutral.

This box looks more like a sub panel, no main disconnect/breaker.

Your location is important, since lack of ground wires look to be in a place that requires metal conduit(also is your ground).

If a sub panel, then grounds cannot be connected to the neutral bus, need a separate ground bus.

If in certain places(Chicago/NY city) the NM-B/romex cables might not be allowed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a main panel - there are grounds (what few exist) and neutrals landing on the same bus.  No main breaker because of the split bus arrangement.